# SQL SUM negative value not being returned

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have an SQL Query that looks like this -

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMemberFundUnits]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @member int,
    @fundcode varchar(15),
    @closingdate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(units) IS Null THEN 0 ELSE SUM(units) END) As fundunits
    FROM pe_minv
    WHERE pmi_member = @member AND pmi_fund = @fundcode AND pmi_invested <= @closingdate

END
```

When I run the stored procedure like this -

```
DECLARE @return_value as float /*int*/

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[getFundUnits]
        @member = 9738,
        @fundcode = N'58193',
        @closingdate = N'07/21/2011'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I get two results. The first is the correct one which is `-0.0060`  and the second @return_value which is `0`

This is also the case when I call the stored procedure from my code, I get a 0 back instead of the -0.0060 that I want.

This is how I am calling the stored procedure from my code:

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("getMemberFundUnits", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim p_pm_member As New SqlParameter("@member", SqlDbType.Int)
    p_pm_member.Value = pm_member
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_pm_member)

    Dim p_fund_code As New SqlParameter("@fundcode", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    p_fund_code.Value = fund_code
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_fund_code)

    Dim p_period_closing_date As New SqlParameter("@closingdate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
    p_period_closing_date.Value = period_closing_date
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_period_closing_date)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Do yu actually mean `SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(nits) IS Null THEN 0` instead `SUM(nits)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @return_value as int
```

Your variable is defined as int. Int can't hold decimal values, so the return value is rounded. Try to declare your var as `float`.

[List of SQL Server data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I did try that and a number of other formats but still comes back as 0.

Comment: Could you post your `CREATE PROC`? Also, there is a typo in your querie's first `SUM` (nits).

Comment: Changing the variable to float won't help: the RETURN inside the stored proc is always int. This doesn't deserve 4 upvotes... so -1

Answer (score 1):

The RETURN is always int so it is truncated inside the stored procedure.
[As per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

> RETURN [ integer_expression ]

You need to use an OUTPUT parameter that is float:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[getFundUnits]
    @member...,
    @fundcode...',
    @closingdate...,
    @SummedValue float OUTPUT
AS
...
SELECT @SummedValue = (CASE WHEN SUM(nits) IS Null THEN 0 ELSE SUM(units) END) As fundunits
...
GO
```

And you call it as

```
DECLARE @return_value as float

EXEC    [dbo].[getFundUnits]
        @member = 9738,
        @fundcode = N'58193',
        @closingdate = N'07/21/2011',
        @return_value OUTPUT

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

RETURN is used (if at all) only for execution status usually: meaningful data is via output parameters or a resultset. I no longer use RETURN...

Comment: I did not downvote this. But it looks like you have not read the question correctly. You are saying he NEEDs to use an output parameter but he is doing the right thing by just selecting the result set as he wants. Also, output parameter can only return one value. May be I'm just confused about what the asker wants.

Comment: @coder net: I assumed that RETRUN was being used for the actual data based on the proc call, before the edit.

Comment: I assume that is just in the management studio. Either way I think the question is confusing. But using a datareader to read the values should work as long as he using a select statement in the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the return value as Decimal with precision.

```
DECLARE @return_value as decimal(18,4)
```

Also, why are you filling a dataset for only returning one column. Use a sqldatareader and retrieve the values as decimal. Dataset is very resource intensive.

Comment: @return_value via RETURN is always int

Comment: Thats not what he is doing inside the stored proc. He is just using a select statement, not using a 'Return'. The other instance is used in the management studio to run the proc. I think the first part of my answer is misleading but the second part should work.